# insertion in a binary tree

Tags: c, binary-tree

How to perform insertion in a binary tree recursively such that it is always filled from the left hand side??? Following is the code that I've written which is of course erroneous...i am a bit weak in recursion...please provide your suggestions...

```
void insert(node **root,int n)
{
     node *temp;
     temp=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
     temp->data=n;
     temp->lchild=NULL;
     temp->rchild=NULL;
     if(*root==NULL)
     {
         *root=temp;
         return;
     }
     if((*root)->lchild==NULL)
     {
          (*root)->lchild=temp;
          return;
     }
     if((*root)->rchild==NULL)
     {
          (*root)->rchild=temp;
          return;
     }
     insert(&((*root)->lchild),n);
     insert(&((*root)->rchild),n);
     return;
}
```

Comment: You will need to know how many elements are in the tree to balance it - or you'll just get a list (left->left->left->left etc).

Comment: tell us if tree should be balanced, complete or a search binary tree. It makes difference in insertion policy.

Comment: its only a binary tree.....so you need to keep track of the policy of a binary tree while insertion...

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.
2. Your program might insert `n` into *both* subtrees.

Comment: it is necessary to cast the return value of malloc since malloc always returns a void pointer...yes it inserts n in both subtrees....how do I modify it???

Comment: **No.** You will only need that cast if you have a `#include` error or if you're using a C++ compiler.  As or fixing your code, @sje397 has a good suggestion in his comment above.  You need to decide in which subtree to insert the new node, not put it in both.

Answer (score 0):

Try Iterative way. Else as suggested by the above user, u will get a list like left->left->left etc.

If you wana approach in iterative way

```
public void insert(String data)
{
    if(node == null)
        node = new Node(null,data,null);
    else
    {
        Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<Node>();
        q.add(node);
        while(q.peek() != null)
        {
            Node temp = q.remove();
            if(temp.left != null)
                q.add(temp.left);
            else
            {
                temp.left = new Node(null,data,null);
                break;
            }

            if(temp.right != null)
            {
                q.add(temp.right);
            }
            else
            {
                temp.right = new Node(null,data,null);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is in Java. I guess its easy to implement in C.